# NSSpeechSynthesizer, stopSpeaking and Nuance voices

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, text-to-speech

I found this strange issue using the Nuance TTS. `startSpeakingString:` and `startSpeakingString:toURL:` work find, but the `stopSpeakingAtBoundary` seems to fail in the `startSpeakingString:toURL:` case.

To test this I implemented the delegate and in the `willSpeakWord...` i put a simple `NSLog()` method to see what word is going to speak. After calling `stopSpeakingAtBoundary` the `NSLog()` continues to be called, this means that the TTS engine did not respond to the stop command.

This problem seems appear only using Nuance voices, for example Alice (IT) or Daniel (US if I remember). This also happens using the compact version of the voice.

Using Alex, for instance, as I call the stop method the word printing process also stops immediately

The code is simply

```
    NSSpeechSynthesizer* synth;
    synth = [NSSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    // setting voice parameters
    [synth startSpeakingString:@"a quite long message..." toURL:aURL];
```

in another method, while converting text to audio...

```
    [synth stopSpeakingAtBoundary:NSSpeechImmediateBoundary];
```

Has any of you encountered this issue? Do you know how could it be fixed? Or can anyone of you suggest me a workaround?

Thank you very much for helping...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this solved the problem for me... The issue was triggered by the `NSSpeechImmediateBoundary` stopping style. Using the `NSSpeechWordBoundary` instead, also the Nuance and the infoVox iVox voices will correctly stop speaking.